# Bypass mongoose getter

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was trying to use mongoose getter to cast all user password before send out. It works perfectly.
However, on method "comparePassword", I need the passwordstring to compare sothen I can authenticate.

Is there a way to bypass the getter under certain conditions in mongoose? Thanks in advance!

Code Example:

```
function castpassword (pw) {
  return 'keyboard cat';
}

var AccountSchema = new Schema({
  password: { type: String, get: castpassword }
});

AccountSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (candidatePassword, cb) {
    // random hash vs keyborad cat === not authenticated
    crypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function (err, isMatch) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        cb(null, isMatch);
    });
};
....

Account.findById( someId, function (err, found) {
  console.log(found.password); // 'keyboard cat'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **this.toObject()** in mongoose will bypass all getter and setter settings in mongoose since it change it to plain JSON data

```
AccountSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (candidatePassword, cb) {
    // keyboard cat vs keyboard cat === authenticated
    crypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.toObject().password, function (err, isMatch) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        cb(null, isMatch);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use mongoose 'lean' to skip all mongoose magic and just pull out a json object.

```
Account
  .findById(someId)
  .lean()
  .exec(function (err, found) {
    console.log(found.password); // actual password
    // you can not use mongoose functions here ex:
    // found.save() will fail
  })
```

Another option would be to set password to 'select: false' in the schema.

```
var AccountSchema = new Schema({
  password: { type: String, select: false }
});
```

This way anytime you pull out the document the password field would not be there at all unless you specifically as for it.

```
Account
  .findById(someId, function (err, found) {
    console.log(found.password); // undefinded
  })

Account
  .findById(someId)
  .select('password') // explicitly asking for password
  .exec(function (err, found) {
    console.log(found.password); // actual password
  })
```

Comment: I get it in static method, but how to use it in instance method like this.lean().password?

Comment: You can't use lean on an instance. Lean can only be used when you are building a query to get the data from the database. By using lean you actually are not returned an instance, you are return raw JSON.

Comment: Actually I found a way use toObject method, thanks for inspiration!